# why newsinglethreadexcutor blocks currentthread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand why `newsinglethreadexecutor` with callable futures' `get()` method blocks the `binderthread` which its initialized in. How can I make them run together?

```
public class main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final process prc = new process();

        prc.run();

        System.out.println("main thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    }


};
```

,,

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class process  {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void run() {

        Future fut = es.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                for (byte b : new byte[]{1,2,3,4,4}){
                    System.out.println(b+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }

                return "aa";
            }
        });


        try {
         //   System.out.println(fut.get(1900L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            System.out.println(fut.get());
        }catch (Exception a){}
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  There is no `get` method on an `ExecutorService`.  Do you mean the `get` method on a `Future<?>` which has been returned after _submitting_ a task to the `ExecutorService`?  This blocks because the purpose of `get` is to access the result of the submitted task, which you can't obtain until the task has completed.

Comment: yes i will edit, it was callable future is blocking, so get is blocking everythread in the app or blocking which threads?

Comment: `get` will block the thread which calls `get`.  (Indirectly, the single thread on your `ExecutorService` will be busy performing the task - or it will be queued for processing later.  Although this is not 'blocked' and isn't caused by the `get` call, it's another thread that can't be doing something else.)  All the other threads in your app should be unaffected (they might be blocked due to other factors, but aren't impacted by the `get` call).

Comment: but binderthread which was eservice. runned on, if get() didnot timeout,, that thread not continues,,, place get() in main function and after it place system.outprint () you will see , main functions method after get() never calls(or after thread sleep ends normally continues),

Comment: interface of that main never calls while using get(), future function has an effect that triggers interface method on main, but if i use get() interface method interfsce not calls or somehow blocking

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking here.  Please share a minimal example of code which highlights the issue you're experiencing so that people can find out further.  I have no information what `binderthread`, `eservice`, or 'thread sleep ends normally continues' reference, or what exception handling you're doing around the timing-out is, etc.

Comment: i have added detail

Comment: And what are you _wanting_ the result to be here?  You call `process.run()`, which submits a task to the `ExecutorService`, but then calls `future.get()` within the `try` block.  This means that the `run()` method will not return until the `Future` is finished (either successfully or otherwise), and so your `main` thread is blocked.  Do you want your `main` thread to have printed it's thread-name _before_ the task has completed (or at least, at the same time, order may depend on how fast the task gets executed)?

Comment: yes iwant main function needs to be run same time not get blocked even if sleep set to 10 min.

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/tj4P1z) an example showing how to let the `main` thread continue in your context.  Let me know if it makes sense.  You can see from the output that the main thread was continuing to the lines afterwards, but then had to wait once `get` was called on the `Future`.  It is up to you _when/where_ you call `get`.

Comment: es.execute() solves that actually but its not returning future

Comment: Yes, although you can't _use_ the result from it then (without writing it out to somewhere else).  The `Future` gives you access to the `"aa"` that your task returns.  But if `execute` is enough for what you're trying to do then by all means.